# Specific use case for wildcards in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace, wildcards

I'm trying to prep HTML code for further editing in WYSIWYG editor and I want to simplify the process as much as possible.

Here's an example of my string

```
<p>C P U xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
```

where 'C P U ' occurs in every case and 'xxxxx' is a variable (both text and length).

What I need to do is turn in into

`<h2>C P U xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</h2>`, essentially preserving everything that's in between the > <

I cannot use regular search/replace beacuse I need to apply the heading style only to the headings. Also, other similar questions that got answered here focused on replacing ends/beginings rather than keeping the middle.

Any answer will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I want to simplify the process as much as possible.

> How do I replace:
>
> ```
> <p>C P U xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
> ```
>
> where 'C P U ' occurs in every case and 'xxxxx' is a variable (both
>   text and length).
>
> With:
>
> ```
> <h2>C P U xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</h2>
> ```

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `[\<]p[\>]C P U (.*)[\<]/p[\>]`
- Set "Replace with" to `<h2>C P U \1</h2>`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

**Before**:

```
<p>C P U xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
```

**After**:

```
<h2>C P U xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</h2>
```

---

#### Further reading

- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)

Comment: @DavidPpostill
Thanks a lot, that saved me a lot of manual work.

Comment: @KrisK You're very welcome ;) The important bit of the regex is "() allow us to access whatever is inside the parentheses." and "The set of parentheses may be accessed with \1" in the replacement string.